# Host relative URL

Tags: html, url

I have `rtmp` and `http` service in the same host, and I have a web page include a video link:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
  <source src="rtmp://[Server IP]/live" type="rtmp/mp4">
</video>
```

Is there a way link to the `rtmp` url without specifying IP/Hostname? (like root-relative or protocol-relative URL)

I know how to do this in JS (`'rtmp://' + location.host + '/live'`), but I want to know is there a pure URL syntax can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not with URL syntax. You must specify everything to the right of the point you are relative to.

Comment: Where can I find the `easy to read` (w3.org too complicate) URL syntax standard? :)